# how to add multi X axis custom line in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to draw multi X-axis vertical custom line in chart js, I got the one example from the `jsfiddle` link `http://jsfiddle.net/mn8x6fso/` if it possible to draw multi-line based on X-axis value with this example. or if possible in javascript?.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around:

```
var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

    var chart = this.chart;
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    var index = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
    if (index) {
      var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

      var aaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yyaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.top);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
      ctx.lineTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.bottom);

      ctx.moveTo(aaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index + 1), yyaxis.top);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#cc0000';
      ctx.lineTo(aaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index + 1), yyaxis.bottom);

      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [65, 0, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
      fill: false
    }],
    lineAtIndex: 2
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: thank you for reply if it is possible to handle dynamically for example `["February", "March", "May","July"]` i want to draw for this 4 month only

Comment: Then just create a function with this code and change the index:

          ctx.moveTo(aaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index + 1), yyaxis.top);
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#cc0000';
         ctx.lineTo(aaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index + 1), yyaxis.bottom);

Comment: Call the next function inside "draw" with the day of the week:

function createLine(weekDayNumber) {
  var aaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
  var yyaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

  ctx.moveTo(aaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, weekDayNumber), yyaxis.top); 
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#cc0000'; ctx.lineTo(aaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, weekDayNumber), yyaxis.bottom);
}

Comment: thanks for the reply I am not getting you. can u rewrite the code above?